# Creating Specific linear regression equations from A larger equation using R

Tags: r, linear-regression

here is a sample of my data, which is found at this link: http://www.uwyo.edu/crawford/datasets/drugreactions.txt
[image]

I made this equation for the data

```
    fit2 <- lm(Allergens~Gender*Race*Druglevel, data=dr)
```

Which spit me out this

[image]

I know how to reorder the data to give a black male baseline with

```
    dr$Race<-factor(dr$Race,levels=c("Black","Latino","Indian","Asian","NativeAmerican","Whit e"))
    dr$Gender<-factor(dr$Gender,levels=c("Male","Female"))
    newfit <- lm(Allergens~Gender*Race, data=dr)
```

However want I want is to be able to take out certain coefficients. For example, say I just want white males and black females to be in the model, instead of all the other categories.
I tried

```
    whitefit <- lm(Allergens~(Gender="Male"), data=dr)
```

But got an error due to uneven rows between allergens and where gender equals male.

Ideally I would like a way to take out any category so that I could completely customize the model and take out things for simplicity sake. For example, taking out male Indians from the model above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subset the data either through indexing or by using the `subset`function:

```
dr <- read.table("http://www.uwyo.edu/crawford/datasets/drugreactions.txt",
                 header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

# Example excluding Indians:
newfit <- lm(Allergens ~ Gender * Race, data = subset(dr, subset = Race != "indian"))

# Example using only White Males and Black Females
wmbf.fit <- lm(Allergens ~ Gender * Race, 
               data = subset(dr, subset = (Race == "White" & Gender == "Male") |
                                          (Race == "Black" & Gender == "Female")))
```

However if you want to exclude a *gender* altogether, you'll need to change your formula to exclude Gender, since all observations will have the same value on Gender and therefore this variable can't possibly contribute to the model.